# mysqli_query SELECT LIKE function not working

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting query error, im using the like LIKE sql function to search for the name submitted by the user.

But msqli_query is giving an error if i remove the LIKE function it works but doesn't works with the LIKE function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Users</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"method="GET">

Name: <input type="text" name="name"></input> 

<input type="submit" name="searchusers" value="Submit"></input> </br>

</body>
</html>

<?php require('connect.php');

$name = @$_GET['name'];


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
{   
$select123 ="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE ='%".$name."%'"; 
$check = mysqli_query($conn, $select123) or die("query error");
mysqli_num_rows($check) or die("Couldnt not find the Specified username");

}
?>
```

Please help

Comment: remove = from like

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: im getting query error because mysqli_query is not working

Comment: @UsamaZafar if i remove the die function msqli_num_rows will give an error as msqli_query is not working

Comment: @YourCommonSense didn't get you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `=` near keyword `like` :

```
$select123 ="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%".$name."%'";
```

Comment: why downvote, they seems correct answer ?

Comment: questions caused by typos have to be voted to close, not answered